# Switching values in slider (windows phone 8.1 silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, slider, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way to switch values in slider so that it goes for example from 100 to 0 instead of 0 to 100 in windows phone 8.1 silverlight app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called [IsDirectionReversed property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.isdirectionreversed%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

> The value of this property determines the direction of increasing
>   value of a Slider. For example, when you move the Thumb control up on
>   a vertical Slider when the IsDirectionReversed property is set to
>   false, the Value of the Slider increases. If the value of the
>   IsDirectionReversed property is changed to true, the Value of the
>   Slider decreases as the Thumb moves up.